# How to fix button

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I wanted to create an app that opens a window and has two buttons that say differnt things. But there seems to be a problem and I do not know how to fix it. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
    package fenster;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Fenster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myFrame=new JFrame ("This is my window.");
        myFrame.setSize(300,400);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        myFrame.add(panel);
        JButton button= new JButton("Hello World!");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new Action1()); // there's an error here

        JButton button2= new JButton("Hello again!");
        panel.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener (new Action2()); // there's an error here

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem right now? What is the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 20 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
package fenster;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Fenster {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame myFrame=new JFrame ("This is my window.");
    myFrame.setSize(300,400);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
public Fenster(){
    JPanel panel= new JPanel();
    myFrame.add(panel);
    JButton button= new JButton("Hello World!");
    panel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        //code here
     }
     } 

    JButton button2= new JButton("Hello again!");
    panel.add(button2);
    button2.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        //code here
    }
    } 

}

}
```

First don't add all your code under the `main` method its better to create a constructor or other methods instead of the `main`.

Second the reason you got an error because `new action2`, here you have to create a class called `Action2` and class called `Action1` . Both these classes should implement `ActionListener`.

Or

You can create an anonymous listener like the one that I did `new ActionListener` that way you dont have to create a class every time.

Check this for more info:
[ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)